# Is there any way to transform the web.config while pressing F5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config, web-config-transform

Is there any way that works integrated with the visual studio that makes a transformation on the web.config based on different profiles and when you press F5?
I understand that slowcheetah so far don't have this options for the webconfigs while you are debugging the application, it only works on the publish. Can any one put me on the right direction?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow

Comment: @Alex not a tool, I want to figure out the way to do it, so far I tried slowcheetah and didn't work for me